# Php send mail script and spam

Tags: php, sendmail

I get this script for sending mails form form in my webpage, but lately when someone send message it goes to spam folder in gmail. My provider say it's because my **from field** is *fake* and get rated by google as spam. And that I should open email account on my domain and redirect form to that mail. I don't wont do that, so is there any workaround to send it to gmail?

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = trim($_POST['email']);
$message= stripslashes($_POST['message']);
$subject  = "poruka od $name";

$mail_send = " Ime: ".
                $name.
                "\nE-mail: ".
                $email.
                "\nPoruka: ".
                $message;
$mail = mail(WEBMASTER_EMAIL, $subject, $mail_send,
     "From: ".$name." <".$email.">\r\n"
    ."Reply-To: ".$email."\r\n"
    ."X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion());
```

Comment: Why not use your own e-mail in the From header, e.,g. `From: youremail@example.com`? The name and e-mail of the visitor are already stored in the contents of the e-mail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can can do this by using **PHPMailer** class.
Just study about it.You have to provide your Email id and Password in that.